# How do I solve this formik onSubmit error with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik

for some reason I'm getting an error on onSubmit prop of Formik:

> Type '(values: { email: string; password: string; }) => { type: string; payload: { email: string | null; password: string | null; }; }' is not assignable to type '((values: { email: string; password: string; }, formikHelpers: FormikHelpers<{ email: string; password: string; }>) => void | Promise) & ((values: { email: string; password: string; }) => { ...; })'.
> Type '(values: { email: string; password: string; }) => { type: string; payload: { email: string | null; password: string | null; }; }' is not assignable to type '(values: { email: string; password: string; }, formikHelpers: FormikHelpers<{ email: string; password: string; }>) => void | Promise'.
> Type '{ type: string; payload: { email: string | null; password: string | null; }; }' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise'.

These are the Formik props:

```
<Formik
                    initialValues={{ email: '', password: ''}}
                    validationSchema = { LoginSchema }
                    validateOnChange={false}
                    onSubmit={ (values) => requestLogin(values.email, values.password)}
                >
```

And this is requestLogin action:

```
export const requestLogin = (email: string, password: string) => ({
type: types.AUTH_USER,
payload: {
    email: email || null,
    password: password || null
}
```

});

Everything should be fine since requestLogin takes 2 parameters of type 'string' or am I missing something here?

Comment: can you share full error message, because I think you missed something

Comment: in your requestLogin function you return an object with type and payload, you should dispatch this function in onSubmit rather than calling it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
onSubmit={ (values) => requestLogin(values.email, values.password) }
```

to

```
onSubmit={ (values) => {requestLogin(values.email, values.password)} }
```

Your error:

```
Type '{ type: string; payload: { email: string | null; password: string | null; }; }' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise'.
```

You're returning an object with type `{ type: string, ... }`, instead of the type `void | Promise` (returning nothing), because arrow functions with no curly brackets automatically return the value inside it.